# problemas com cycle for

Tags: r, for

Estou com uma duvida bastante simples, mas que ainda não descobri a solução. Eu tenho este df:

```
        High Low  Middle
current 0.51 0.43 0.22  
former  0.92 0.28 0.21  
never   0.78 0.22 0.9
```

e eu querias que os valores < 0.75 ficassem `NA`.

Eu fiz este ciclo:

```
for (element in ncol(df)) {
  df[which(df[element]< 0.75)] == "NA"
}
```

Não substitui os valores <0.75, por `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

Para esta situação há uma solução mais simples, basta utilizar o `base::replace`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(High = c(0.51, 0.92, 0.78),
                 Low  = c(0.43, 0.28, 0.22),
                 Middle = c(0.22, 0.21, 0.9),
                 nomes = c("current", "former", "never"))
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  tibble::column_to_rownames("nomes")
df2
```

```
> df2
        High  Low Middle
current 0.51 0.43   0.22
former  0.92 0.28   0.21
never   0.78 0.22   0.90
```

```
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  base::replace(.<0.75, NA)
df3
```

```
> df3
        High Low Middle
current   NA  NA     NA
former  0.92  NA     NA
never   0.78  NA    0.9
```

---

Caso realmente seja indispensável o `for`.

```
m <- matrix(nrow = nrow(df2), ncol = ncol(df2))

for (j in 1:ncol(m)) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
    x <- ifelse(df2[i, j] < 0.75, NA, df2[i, j])
    m[i, j] <- x

  }
}

m
```

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,] 0.92   NA   NA
[3,] 0.78   NA  0.9
```

```
df4 <- m %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(nomes = df1$nomes)
colnames(df4) <- colnames(df1)
df4 <- df4 %>% 
  tibble::column_to_rownames("nomes")
df4
```

```
> df4
        High Low Middle
current   NA  NA     NA
former  0.92  NA     NA
never   0.78  NA    0.9
```